# How to save a pdf file in a browser window without downloading it again?

Tags: finder, safari, google-chrome, pdf

Typically on my Macbook Pro, I click on URLs to pdf documents and they open in a browser window (say, Safari or Chrome), and later if I wish to keep a copy of the pdf file, I click the down arrow icon.

However, the down arrow icon actually attempts to fetch the pdf file from the server again, whereas I already have a local copy in a browser cache somewhere. So, it is an inefficient use of bandwidth. Furthermore, sometimes the original file may no longer be available at the server, or I may not be having Internet access, etc., and I want to save a copy of the file.

Do I need to go searching for the file in the browser cache somehow? Or is there a more convenient way?

Comment: For me, using Safari, clicking the 'save' icon (that appears towards the bottom of the screen when you move the mouse over that area) instantly saves the file to the Downloads folder, and does not reload the file. I have no experience with Chrome, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a PDF file in the browser window you can just go to the File menu and save the file. It will save as a regular PDF and you can choose where to save it.

Comment: Hmm .. tried that, at least, in Chrome, and am getting a "Failed - Forbidden" error in one case, and in the other case, it is trying to save as html. Any idea why?

Comment: I don't know. I use Safari and it works for me. Be sure the web site ends in ,pdf.

Comment: In the first case, yes, it ends in .pdf, and it looks like a normal pdf file, but "Failed - Forbidden" looks suspiciously like a http 403 error to me, like it's still somehow either trying to reload the pdf from the server, or somehow the server allows transfer to my browser but not subsequently saving it (is that even possible?)

Comment: In the second case, it ends in .pdf, sort of .. there is a parameter after the .pdf .. something like "?extra=n7aaz ..", so maybe that confuses the browser into thinking it is html when I try to save it?

Comment: Are you using safari or Chrome?

Comment: These were both with Chrome.

Comment: let me try chrome.

Comment: i tried this site https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf  and when I saved it I got a box and it said save as pdf.

Comment: So chrome worked fine for me. i don't know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: 'm on east coast so i'm calling it a night. keep me posted and if it still doesn't work i can look at it again tomorrow.

Comment: After both servers became available again, I could reload, and then save the PDFs normally. I suspect there may be some time-out restrictions imposed by chrome, as both tabs had been opened for days after loading the PDFs. Didn't realise that that might be the problem when I wrote the question.